# Symfony one entity join many entities

Tags: symfony, orm, entity

I have a user entity with join other entities like Runner, basketball player, football player,...). Each athletic has spécifications fields, so i create user entity that joins Runner entity, basketball entity, football entity. These athletic joins user entity, but this solution is not suiable because the admin must add new Athletic type with spécifications fields, it is not suitable also to ask developper to create new entity for each new Athletic type I think first add json data field into user entity, but how admin Can specify the type of the new field, and i Can implements this kinds of json fields on the form.

Thank You for your help

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. Why does a user join multiple sportsmen? Is he a coach/team leader? And what you intended with saying "join". I see that English is not your first language, but you need to elaborate on this if you want an answer.

Comment: User table contains commons fields for all sport type, each sport type has specifics fields, so i must create à user entity that joins others entity, but my problem how i can do that the administrator can add à new entity for a new sport type with specifics fields ?

Comment: So they are sport types. And the relation shall mean "user practices sport"?

Comment: Yes. But the administrator can not create new entity sport with specifics fields?

Comment: You tagged with UML. So you are after a UML solution?

Comment: No i don't have UML solutions, my problem is on Symfony side. How an administrator can add new entity ?

Comment: Then please don't tag with UML if you are not interested in that!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you.

If I understand what you have written I think you just need to add one property to your User Entity. A User entity may be a football player or a runner etc.
So just add a sportType property to your User entity.

If a user may have multiples sportType then maybe you could use 3 tables in your database:
1 table called user
1 table called sports
1 table called user_sports

Table user

```
ID Name   email          ...
1  Name1  bob@gmail.com  ...
2  Name2  foo@gmail.com  ...
3  Name3  bar@gmail.com  ...
```

Table sport

```
ID Name
1  football
2  basketball
3  running
```

Table user_sport

```
ID user_id sport_id
1  1        3
2  8        1
3  1        2
.. ..       ..
```

Because one user may have many sports then it is a "one to many" relation. You can see on the [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) how to set this kind of relation on your entities.

Update:
If I understand your admin will add fields to a Sport Entity and you do not know how many field a sport Entity will be having.

You can use the Data Transformers component. Take a look here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

When you build the form to let your admin add a new Sport entity you can give him a TextAreaType. The admin will add manually a valid json into this TextAreaField

When the admin sends the form to your controller it will transform your TextAreaType according to the way you've defined in SportType.

Exemple:

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/SportType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;

// ...

class SportType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('sportJsonFields', TextAreaType::class); //here you give the texterea to your admin so he inserts a json manually

        $builder->get('sportJsonFields') 
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($SportJsonFieldsJson) {
                    // transform the json datas to a string
                    return json_decode($tagsAsArray);
                },
                function ($tagsAsString) {
                    // transform the string back to a valid json
                    return json_encode($SportJsonFieldsTextArea);
                }
            ))
        ;
    }

}
```

Comment: I know i must join user table with others tables, now i have just 3 sport type, but if the administrator want to add a new sport type with specifics fields, how i can do    ?

Comment: thanks you, i don't know "addModelTransformer", i try to understand that, i think it is a good solution to save json data in a field, because in Symfony a user(admin role) can not create an new entity.

Comment: Ok try to implement that solution and if you like it then don't forget to accept the answer please ;-)